# How to fix "Navigator does not exist" error in basic Expo app?

Tags: react-native, debugging, react-navigation, expo

Getting this error when debugging, when clicking on any tab.  App appears to work fine but of course this disrupts debugging.

> This is the basic app from scratch.

[image: Error message in Expo]

Comment: Can you debug this further? What does the call stack say?

Comment: At least part of stack trace is visible in lower-left corner @ide - however we gave up on this route and decided to port our code into a from-scratch Expo app.  Thanks for the interest in helping.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? Happens everytime I use hot reloading

Comment: @KarlTaylor No, we couldn't get Expo working well and went back to Vanilla React Native.  Here's our blog post about the experience: https://medium.com/2-minute-revolution-developer-blog/our-review-of-expo-and-why-we-dont-think-it-s-ready-for-prime-time-bb0897657295